# Exception in Establishing JDBC Connection

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I've used the following piece of code to load the driver. But it shows the exception

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class TestConnection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            System.out.println("Loading driver...");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Driver loaded!");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find the driver in the classpath!", e);
        }     
    }
}
```

Please help me !!!!

Comment: Please add the stacktrace.

Comment: is Driver jar in your classpath?

Comment: If your driver jar inside your class path, So we are helpless to debug issues in absence of stack trace, can you post stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the message is very self-explanatory. The driver class is not in the classpath. Add the MySQL Connector/J jar-file to your classpath to resolve this error. You can either do it manually or add this fragment to your pom if you are using Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.34</version>
</dependency>
```

Since this is a JDBC 4.0 driver you don't have to call `Class.forName(...)`. The `DriverManager` will find a suitable driver for the given URL if there is one in the classpath.

Comment: There's no MySQL connector in class path. How to add one ?

Comment: Google that. There are lots of tutorials on how to do that. It also depends on your development environment. If you are using eclipse, check Method 2 in this article: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)